# Slow copy/move transfer rate

Tags: 14.04, ntfs, ssd, transfer

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 and am experiencing extremely slow transfer (copy/move) rates between my Ubuntu drive (SSD) and an NTFS 7200rpm HDD (SATAII) that I use as storage. By slow I mean around 1-1.3Mb/s. I haven't0 found any solution on any forum so far.

I have tried both with cp and with rsync and the same rate is observed.

On the same laptop I also have Windows8.1 installed (on a 2nd SSD) and I experience very fast transfer rates to the HDD.

Would anybody have a piece of advice?

Thank you,

Chris

Comment: Yes indeed. It is a 7200rpm HDD

Answer (score 1):

NTFS support in Linux has improved considerably recently, but it is still surprisingly slow.

While 1.3MB/s seems unusually slow, I could believe it happening if you were copying many small files or something.

At least as a troubleshooting step, you could try formatting the same drive using a different filesystem.  But you probably don't want to do that if you have lots of data on it.

Comment: It's actually usually pretty big files that I transfer, and even if it is a single file I get this issue. I need it to be as NTFS as I need this drive as storage/shared drive for both Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu.

Comment: The open source NTFS-3G driver is pretty slow and crippled.  You could shrink the partition and try to add a new partition with another type if you really wanted to find out of it's Ubuntu's slow NTFS or if it's the drive.

Comment: Because I do not observe such reduced transfer rates when transfering files within my Ubuntu SSD, nor from my Windows SSD to the NTFS HDD, I doubt that the problem comes from the drive itself. Also, this only happens when transfering from the Ubuntu SSD or the Windows SSD (under Ubuntu) to the HDD, and not the opposite, so I assume that something is limiting the transfer rate in that direction...

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it's 720rpm, then I'd say that's your problem. ;-)

How is the NTFS volume mounted? If done via /etc/fstab, then try adding "async" to the mount options, or if "sync" is already there, change it to "async", remount your drive and try again.

Comment: The volume (I didn't mention that it is an internal HDD) was immediately recognised by Ubuntu so I haven´t mounted it manually. When I run mount here is the output: /dev/sda2 on /media/chris/Storage type fuseblk (rw,nosuid,nodev,allow_other,default_permissions,blksize=4096)

Comment: Hi Jeff, I am not very familiar with this and would not want to do something wrong. My NTFS volume is currently mounted in /media. This is where it appeared automatically as I installed Ubuntu. So far I have been unable to check whether the drive is mounted as sync or async. How can I check this and how should I change it to async if it is mounted as sync? Thanks!